# How do I fix setState typescript argument errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I just wanna know what to do to fix this, and where to learn how to format this stuff properly. Any guidance is appreciated, anyways I'm getting an error in typescript when I try to pass in the useState object that I'm using for my useState.

[The error I'm getting is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBMVM.png)

How am I supposed to declare the types of arrow function variables when I'm using useState? This one is complex and it's throwing a bunch of errors. This is to dynamically provide the phone type options of a prop that's attached to our phone input prop. The code works fine, I just wanna pass this into the useState without getting this dang error, and learn how to pass stuff into the useState properly

Here's the code that handles this section:

```
  const [availablePhoneTypes, setAvailablePhoneTypes] = useState<PhoneTypes[]>(ALL_PHONE_TYPES);
  const [currentPhoneTypes, setCurrentPhoneTypes] = useState<[{index: number, type: string}]>([]);
  const handlePhoneTypeChange = (
    e: any,
    index: number
  ) => {
    const selectedPhoneType = e.target.value;
    // const tmp = availablePhoneTypes.filter(type => type != selectedPhoneType);
    // setAvailablePhoneTypes(tmp);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
  
    // Manage/Update the selected phone types
    if (currentPhoneTypes.filter((data: {index: number;}) => data.index === index).length != 0) {
      const updateCurrentPhoneTypes = currentPhoneTypes.map((data: {index: number, type: string;}) => {
        if (data.index == index) data.type = e;
        return data;
      });
      setCurrentPhoneTypes(updateCurrentPhoneTypes);
    } else {
      // .push may throw an error on the useState currentPhoneTypes
      // const currentPhoneTypesInsert = 
      setCurrentPhoneTypes(currentPhoneTypes.push({index: index, type: selectedPhoneType}));
      console.log(`index: ${index}, type: ${selectedPhoneType}, new current phone types`, currentPhoneTypes);
    }
  
    // Set the available phone types 
    const theSelectedPhoneTypes = currentPhoneTypes.map(data: {type: string;} => data.type);
    const unselectedPhoneTypes = ALL_PHONE_TYPES.filter(type => !theSelectedPhoneTypes.includes(type));
    console.log('Here are the selected phone types: ', theSelectedPhoneTypes);
    console.log('the available phone types: ', unselectedPhoneTypes);
  
    setAvailablePhoneTypes(unselectedPhoneTypes);
  };
```

If you guys are curious about the code I'll be here, gonna work on this for another hour tonight after I take a break to see what you guys think. I appreciate it, anything will help!

Answer (score 1):

Line 2 is wrong. `[{index: number, type: string}]` declares an array literal with a fixed number of elements (i.e. a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)). It should be `{index: number, type: string}[]` (or `Array<{index: number, type: string}>`)

```
  const [currentPhoneTypes, setCurrentPhoneTypes] = useState<{index: number, type: string}[]>([]);
```

Comment: This is supposed to be an array though. There will be up to 4 phone numbers declared at a time, each having a type. I wanna use a usestate variable to keep track of each phone number (by index), and the associated type of each because each type must be unique. Wait is that how I declare the array of objects?

Comment: @roninMo I just showed you. Read it again. `{index: number, type: string}[]` (or `Array<{index: number, type: string}>` both declare an array of objects. :)